# Bundle / Node / web pack error when creating new rails app

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, npm, webpack

Good morning,

I am trying to generate a new rails app, but have run into a whole bunch of errors. Which appears to be webpacker & or node related.

- I have tried uninstalling node and webpacker and reinstalling.
- I have tried downloading node.js again.
- I have tried ; run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32   java
  that dosn;t work as a gemfile could not be located.
- I have tried https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
- I been through various threads regarding this but nothing seems to resolve the issue

I am a new coder, any advice would be appreciated. I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.4

`` The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`. ``

```
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
```

```
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/gemmag/code/gemmage3/rails-mister-cocktail-2/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.1.0
gyp info using node@12.16.2 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at \"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python\"
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.2/node-v12.16.2-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.2/node-v12.16.2-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.2/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.16.2/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp info spawn /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/gemmag/code/gemmage3/rails-mister-cocktail-2/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/gemmag/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.16.2/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/gemmag/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.16.2',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/gemmag/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.16.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/gemmag/code/gemmage3/rails-mister-cocktail-2/node_modules/fsevents',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be missing the xcode command line tools.

Try running `xcode-select --install` first

Answer (score 0):

I tried running  `xcode-select --install`

It returned:

```
> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates.
```

I then tried `softwareupdate --list`

which returned:

```
Finding available software
No new software available.
```